# How to create an incremental list using shortcodes?

Tags: shortcode

Right now I'm creating shortcodes like this:

```
function short_code($atts) {
  $a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'name' => ''
  ), $atts );

return '<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <p>' . esc_attr($a['name']) . '</p>
  </div>
</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'short-code', 'short_code' );

// Usage: [short-code name="John"]
```

How to do it so I can have incremental shortcodes? In other words, to modify the shortcode so I can do this? `[short-code name="John" name="Jack" name="Mary"]` and produce something like this?

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <p>John</p>
    <p>Jack</p>
    <p>Mary</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I searched on [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=shortcode%20%20list%20wordpress) but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to use shortcode attributes. I Googled "wordpress shortcode attributes" and found the sample code below in the WP [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

```
// [bartag foo="foo-value"]
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something',
        'bar' => 'something else',
    ), $atts );

    return "foo = {$a['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

You would want to pass an array for the example you show in your question

```
[short-code names="John", "Jack", "Mary"]
```

You can get the list of names by following the sample code and accessing the names array:

```
foreach($a['names'] as $name){
    echo "<p>$name</p>";
}
```

Edit:
Just to be clear you would get the array from args as such:

```
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
    'names' => 'names'
), $atts );
```